# Get tr id by clicking on tbody

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

Can someone tell me how can I get tr id when `dblclick` event listener to tbody?

My table is as follows:

```
<table>
  <tbody id="patient_table">
    <tr id="1">
      <td class="td20">Patient Name</td>
      <td class="td20">Summary</td>
      <td class="td20">Created</td>
      <td class="td20">Last visit</td>
      <td class="td20">Refer to a Doctor</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="2">
      <td class="td20">Patient Name</td>
      <td class="td20">Summary</td>
      <td class="td20">Created</td>
      <td class="td20">Last visit</td>
      <td class="td20">Refer to a Doctor</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The script is as follows:

```
$("tbody").on('dblclick','td',function (e) {
    var id = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');
    alert(id);
});
```

This works [here](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/Ma9SR/1/), but not in my code. When debugging it shows:

> TypeError: $(...).on is not a function

BTW, I found this solution in another post.

Comment: is jquery included in your code?

Comment: Have you imported the jQuery file? Can we see all of your code?

Comment: IDs starting with numbers are only valid starting with HTML5, and may behave unpredictably in older browsers. Also, it leaves you much more likely to use duplicate IDs. Consider using `<tr data-id="1">` instead.

Comment: Include Jquery :
`<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>`

And Wrap Your Code Inside:
`$(document).ready(function(){ //here });`

Comment: `on()` only works using jQuery 1.7+.

Comment: @AshotArakelyan Have you included any other js libraries like prototype, mootools or any other along with jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method `on` was introduced in jQuery version 1.7.

I think you have to upgrade your jQuery library to the newest version.

Otherwise, you can use `live` instead:

```
$("tbody td").live('dblclick',function (e) {
var id = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');
alert(id);
});
```

Comment: this is not correct syntax for live method: `$('td').live('dblclick',handler)` or better use `delegate()` instead: `$("tbody").delegate('td', 'dblclick',handler)`

Comment: @A.Wolff:updated now..

Comment: I'm calling jquery 1.8.17 <script src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: live is calling dblclick event but still I'm getting undefined

Comment: great, that works, I forgot to add td after tbody.

Comment: strange why it doesn't work with on, while I'm calling jquery 1.8. library